# I get RESULT_OK before ending activity

Tags: android

I have any activity that start other other activity for getting some items ,

I have started that  with

```
Intent inte = new Intent(actMain.this,actResults.class);
inte.setAction("calllog");
startActivityForResult(inte, CALL_LOG_REQ);
```

but after starting this , actResults returns Action_OK automatically , and when I send ACTION_OK , it do not works . why ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting an activity is an asynchronous process.  When you call `startActivityForResult`, the other activity is started and control immediately proceeds to the next line of your code.

In order to check the results of this call, you need to override:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent intent)
```

method.  In that method, check `reqCode` - if it is your `CALL_LOG_REQ`, then check the `resCode` for the actual result.  If extra data was passed back, then you can get it from the `intent` parameter.